# React passing state between instances of the same Component

Tags: reactjs, parameters, state, browser-history

I'm fairly new to React, and I was trying to create an app that functioned thusly:

- The app consists of several Pages, with multiple Components on each Page.
- One of these Components is **stats**, which can change as the user interacts with Components on the Page.
- When a user clicks on a certain Component, they will be taken to a "different" page, which is really just another Page, with different text, data, etc. This is carried out through the browserHistory.push() method. I would like to be able to carry over the changed 'stats' component from one Page to the next, but I am not sure how to do so. Furthermore, since I set the default value for **stats** in the Page component, it seems that any attempt at passing the changed values into the new Page would result in the new values being overridden. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**State should live above the level of all components that need access to that state.**

Remember that one of the principles of React is "one-way" data flow down the component hierarchy. Essentially, data/state should live at a high level, getting passed down to child components and consumed as needed.

In your case, you have some "stats" data that needs to be displayed across multiple Pages. So, "stats" needs to be owned by a component above *all* of your Page components - perhaps at the root component of the app itself. Pages themselves would just take the data in and render it, potentially with some callbacks appropriate for editing the data.

Read a bit more about Facebook's philosophy for React in "Thinking in React" in the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live

Comment: Alright, so now stats is held in the root App, which is good. The trouble is this - in the Page code, the update is not really associated with an easily-defined user action (a click, for instance), instead it happens automatically if certain conditions are met. I already have a relevant changeStats method in the Root App, but now I need to know how to send a callback to Page through React-router, then have that callback (which will trigger changeStats) happen when the necessary conditions are met in **Page**.

Comment: @EoinMoloney I'm having trouble finding good documentation on it but you can pass props through Routes by simply adding it to the Route as a prop, such as `<Route component={MyComponent} someCustomProp="foo" />` and then accessing it in MyComponent with `this.props.route.someCustomProp`.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, I just need some way to access a variable belonging to **App** within a Component that's a child of **App**. If you wish, I can send you a link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/ProfHats/ParaQuest  the only relevant files are index.js (where App is located) and adventurePage (it's a mess, but search for the part where it checks **switch(StatsIncrease.type)**

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is to use [React Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to store the state of your application.  You would then use `mapStateToProps` (See [Redux API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) for details) to map the state into props for your `stats` component.